# How can I read characters until a specific one in Java?

Tags: java, file, char, external-sorting

I want to read a few words from a file. I didn't found any method to do this, so I decided to read **char by char**, but I need to stop at the spaces to store the read word in my array and go to the next one.

I'm making an external sorting aplication, that's why I have a memory limitation, and, in that case, I can't just use `readLine()` and then `split()`, I need to have a control of what I read.

The `read()` method returns an **int** and I have no idea of what can I do to `read()` method return a **char** and stop reading after a space.

This is my code this far:

```
protected static String [] readWords(String arqName, int amountOfWords) throws IOException {
    FileReader arq = new FileReader(arqName);
    BufferedReader lerArq = new BufferedReader(arq);

    String[] words = new String[amountOfWords];

    for (int i = 0; i < amountOfWords; i++){
        //words[i] = lerArq.read();
    }

    return words;
}
```

**Edit 1:** I used a **Scanner** and the `next()` method, it worked. Scanner's initialization is at Main.

```
static String [] readWords(int amountOfWords, Scanner leitor) throws IOException {
    String[] words= new String[amountOfWords];

    for (int i = 0; i < amountOfWords; i++){
        words[i] = leitor.next();
    }

    return words;
}
```

Comment: read line by line using the nextLine() function and then call split(" ") to generate an array of words, assuming the words are only separated by a single space

Comment: You can read one word at a time using `Scanner.next()`. See this for example https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_next.htm

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz I aprecciate the answer, but as I said in the question, I can't just use nextLine(), because of the memory limitation.

Comment: @SergeiSirik I'll try it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read it char by char (so you have more control over what you want to store and what you don't), you could try something like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;

[...]

public static String readNextWord(BufferedReader reader) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    int currentData;

    do {
        currentData = reader.read();

        if(currentData < 0) {
            if(builder.length() == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            else {
                return builder.toString();
            }
        }
        else if(currentData != ' ') {
            /* Since you're talking about words, here you can apply
             * a filter to ignore chars like ',', '.', '\n', etc. */

            builder.append((char) currentData);
        }

    } while (currentData != ' ' || builder.length() == 0);

    return builder.toString();
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
String[] words = new String[amountOfWordsToRead];

for (int i = 0; i < amountOfWordsToRead; i++){
    words [i] = readNextWord(yourBufferedReader);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this will be helpful.

It's not a problem to use `read()`. Just cast the result to a character:

```
...
for (int i = 0; i < memTam; i++) {
      // this should work. you will get the actual character
      int current = lerArq.read();
      if (current != -1) {
          char c = (char) current;
          // then you can do what you need with this character
      }
}
...
```

The method returns character read, as an integer in the range 0 to 65535 or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached.

I won't add a lot of theory about encodings, how it's done in Java, etc. because I am not aware of some very low-level details. I have a basic high-level understanding of how it works.

Every single key on your keyboard has a number associated with it. Every single character that you type can be translated into a decimal number. For example, `A` becomes the number `65`. This is a standard and it is globally recognized.

*At this point, I hope you can agree it's not that weird that `read()` method returns a number and not the actual character :)*

There is something called the ASCII table which represents all those codes(numbers) for all the keys on your keyboard.

Here it is just to show how ot looks:

```
Dec  Char                           Dec  Char     Dec  Char     Dec  Char
---------                           ---------     ---------     ----------
  0  NUL (null)                      32  SPACE     64  @         96  `
  1  SOH (start of heading)          33  !         65  A         97  a
  2  STX (start of text)             34  "         66  B         98  b
  3  ETX (end of text)               35  #         67  C         99  c
  4  EOT (end of transmission)       36  $         68  D        100  d
  5  ENQ (enquiry)                   37  %         69  E        101  e
  6  ACK (acknowledge)               38  &         70  F        102  f
  7  BEL (bell)                      39  '         71  G        103  g
  8  BS  (backspace)                 40  (         72  H        104  h
  9  TAB (horizontal tab)            41  )         73  I        105  i
 10  LF  (NL line feed, new line)    42  *         74  J        106  j
 11  VT  (vertical tab)              43  +         75  K        107  k
 12  FF  (NP form feed, new page)    44  ,         76  L        108  l
 13  CR  (carriage return)           45  -         77  M        109  m
 14  SO  (shift out)                 46  .         78  N        110  n
 15  SI  (shift in)                  47  /         79  O        111  o
 16  DLE (data link escape)          48  0         80  P        112  p
 17  DC1 (device control 1)          49  1         81  Q        113  q
 18  DC2 (device control 2)          50  2         82  R        114  r
 19  DC3 (device control 3)          51  3         83  S        115  s
 20  DC4 (device control 4)          52  4         84  T        116  t
 21  NAK (negative acknowledge)      53  5         85  U        117  u
 22  SYN (synchronous idle)          54  6         86  V        118  v
 23  ETB (end of trans. block)       55  7         87  W        119  w
 24  CAN (cancel)                    56  8         88  X        120  x
 25  EM  (end of medium)             57  9         89  Y        121  y
 26  SUB (substitute)                58  :         90  Z        122  z
 27  ESC (escape)                    59  ;         91  [        123  {
 28  FS  (file separator)            60  <         92  \        124  |
 29  GS  (group separator)           61  =         93  ]        125  }
 30  RS  (record separator)          62  >         94  ^        126  ~
 31  US  (unit separator)            63  ?         95  _        127  DEL
```

So, imagine you have a `.txt` file with some text - all the letters have corresponding numbers.

The problem with ASCII is that ASCII defines 128 characters, which map to the numbers 0–127 (all of the upper-case letters, lower-case letters, 0-9 digits and a few more symbols).

But there are many more different characters/symbols in the world (different alphabets, emoji, etc.), so there has to be another encoding system to represent them all.

It is called Unicode. Unicode is exactly the same thing for characters whose codes are 0-127. But in general, Unicode can represent a much much wider range of symbols.

In Java, the `char` data type (and therefore the value that a `Character` object encapsulates) are based on the original Unicode specification, which defined characters as fixed-width 16-bit entities. You can check more details in this [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html).
In other words, all Strings in Java are represented in UTF-16.

Hope, after this long story, it makes some sense why you get numbers when read, but you can cast them to type `char`. And again, it's just a kind of high-level overview. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Um, actually, `char` is a UTF-16 code unit value. UTF-16 is one of several encodings for the [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) character set. `FileReader` uses the system default encoding and converts to UTF-16. Where and how the system default encoding is useful is a whole other issue.

Comment: @TomBlodget That is a very good comment. You are absolutely right about UTF-16, but Unicode is a superset of ASCII, and the numbers 0–128 have the same meaning in ASCII as they have in Unicode. Am I right ? My idea was just basically explain that even though the method  returns integer it is actually a character and can be used like that. But maybe I had to be more explicit.

Comment: Numbers have meaning when interpreted with the wrong character encoding? (Dogmatically, no, but pedagogically, yes—as long as the learner already knows ASCII; But there isn't any particular reason they should unless they are working with RFC 7231 or other standards.)

Comment: @TomBlodget not agree. there was nothing about encoding stuff (like Java uses ASCII for strings or so), but I updated my answer anyway. If you have time, you are welcome to take a look )